# Everybody/Somebody don't vs doesn't

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Which one of the followings are correct:

1. Everybody don't want to do it
2. Everybody doesn't want to do it.
3. Somebody don't believe you.
4. Somebody doesn't believe you.

Comment: which are right in your mind?

Comment: @jonMark Everybody doesn't want to do it and Somebody doesn't believe you seems to be correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? Why are you unsure about what is correct in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question is whether "everybody" is singular or plural. To answer that, I [used a dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/everybody) to confirm that it means "every person," and is treated as *singular*. The same is true of "somebody," which means "some person."

Since the subject is singular, now we just have to know how to make the verb match the subject and tense.  Since we're choosing between "do" and "does," we can conclude that all the phrases are in present tense, because the third-person past tense forms of "do" are "did," whether plural or singular. So we want the form of "do" that matches *third-person singular present tense*.

By looking at [the definition of the word "do"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/do) we find that the third-person singular present tense form of "do" is "**does**."

So picking between your choices, we decide that 2 and 4 are correct because "doesn't" is a contraction for "does not."

> Everybody **does** not.
>
> Somebody **does** not.
>
> Everybody **doesn't**.
>
> Somebody **doesn't**.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 1 or 2 I'd say "Nobody wants to do it" or "Not everybody wants to do it", depending on the intended meaning.

However, the expected solution is probably 2 and 4, because "everybody" and "somebody" are treated as singular.